# c# Printing all subsets of a string array with recursion

Tags: c#, recursion

So I have this array:

```
string[] words = {'test', 'rock', 'fun'}
```

and I have to print all subsets, so the result must be

> (), (test), (rock), (fun), (test rock), (test fun),(rock fun), (test
>   rock fun)

This is my code so far

```
    static int x = 0;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] words = { "test", "rock", "fun" };
        string[] helperArray = new string[3];

        NestedLoops(words, helperArray, 0, 0);
    }

    static void NestedLoops(string[] words, string[] helperArray, int index, int start)
    {
        if (index == x)
        {
            PrintArray(helperArray);              
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = start; i < 3; i++)
            {

                helperArray[index] = words[i];
                NestedLoops(words, helperArray, index + 1, i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    static void PrintArray(string[] array)
    {
        Console.Write("(");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" {0}", array[i]);
        }
        Console.Write(")");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

I just don't know how to make x increase as the cycle finishes, now I just get these results

> x = 0 - ()
>
> x = 1 - (test), (rock), (fun)
>
> x = 2 - (test rock), (test fun),(rock fun)

etc..

I'm new to recursion so I'm sorry if the question is stupid..

Edit:

I fugured it out, even though its not very elegant.

Added for cycle to the main method

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] words = { "test", "rock", "fun" };
            string[] helperArray = new string[3];

            for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                NestedLoops(words, helperArray, 0, 0, i);
            }

        }
```

and added variable x to the nested loops recursion

```
static void NestedLoops(string[] words, string[] helperArray, int index, int start, int x)
        {
            if (index == x)
            {
                PrintArray(helperArray);              
            }
```

Comment: Have you already understood recursion to understand recursion? If you did not, understand recursion first. Oh, by the way: https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion&oq=recu&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60j0l3.1523j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Leri cute but not really helping

Comment: @o_weisman It's after edit. ;)

Comment: If this is just a simple three fields array, then why don't you print them normally?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it pretty easily with the help of linq. I an giving a sample code here.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> SubSetsOf(List<string> source)
{
    if (!source.Any())
        return Enumerable.Repeat(Enumerable.Empty<string>(), 1);

    var element = source.Take(1);

    var haveNots = SubSetsOf(source.Skip(1).ToList()).ToList();
    var haves = haveNots.Select(element.Concat);

    return haves.Concat(haveNots);
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
        string[] words = { "test", "rock", "fun" };
        var subSetsOf = SubSetsOf(words.ToList());
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't even compile. What did you mean in the line var haves = haveNots.Select(element.Concat);

Comment: There is no reason for this code not to compile unless you are missing necessary using directive. can you check you have linq included?

Comment: I have "using System.Linq" in my code. Do I need something else?

Comment: @o_weisman This code has dependency on three namespaces: `System`, `System.Collections.Generic`, `System.Linq`.

Comment: It seems a lot easier, but I'm kinda just starting programming, so I have no idea what most of those things do. Thanks though.